# How Different Are Two (LaTeX) Files?

Tags: latexdiff

I needed to understand which of my chapters I had changed the most over the last year.  There are of course many metrics that one can use to measure how different files are, but I decided that I wanted to use consecutive word pairs.  I thought I would just share this little utility program for others with similar needs.

Emphasis of program was on simplicity.  A quick hack, also easily modifiable.

This is not the same need as the highly recommended latexdiff program.  I needed a basic difference statistic, not a way to reconcile the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use utf8;

use warnings FATAL => qw{ uninitialized };

use Perl6::Slurp;

use Math::BigFloat;
sub round { Math::BigFloat->new(shift)->bfround(1); }


=pod

=head1 Title

  wordpairdiff.pl --- compare two text files by the frequency of consecutive word pairs

=cut

my $verbose=1;

my $usage = "$0: oldfile.tex newfile.tex";

(@ARGV) or die $usage;
($#ARGV < 2) or die "$usage: need exactly two filenames as arguments\n";

($ARGV[0]) or die "$usage: need first filename\n";
(-e $ARGV[0]) or die "$usage: first file $ARGV[0] does not exist\n";
my $ofnm= $ARGV[0];

($ARGV[1]) or die "$usage: need second filename\n";
(-e $ARGV[1]) or die "$usage: second file $ARGV[1] does not exist\n";
my $nfnm= $ARGV[1];



my @npairs = slurp( $nfnm ) =~ /(?=(\S+\s+\S+))\S+/g;  ## create consecutive word pairs
my @opairs = slurp( $ofnm ) =~ /(?=(\S+\s+\S+))\S+/g;

my %seen = ();
foreach (@npairs) { ++$seen{$_}; }
foreach (@opairs) { --$seen{$_}; }

my $pos=0; my $neg=0;
foreach my $wpair (keys %seen) {
  ($seen{$wpair} == 0) and next;
  ($seen{$wpair} > 0) and $pos+= $seen{$wpair};
  ($seen{$wpair} < 0) and $neg-= $seen{$wpair};
}

my $aseen=(scalar keys %seen);
my $changes= $pos + $neg;

print "$ofnm vs. $nfnm: ".round(100*(($changes)/($aseen)),3)."%";
($verbose) and print "\t(Changes: $changes.  Word Pairs Examined: $aseen, Neg: $neg, Pos: $pos)";
print "\n";
```

Sample Use:

```
$ wpairdiff oldfile.tex newfile.tex
oldfile.tex vs. newfile.tex: 12%    (Changes: 491.  Word Pairs Examined: 3935, Neg: 306, Pos: 185)
```